# École Normale Supérieure's students' class rankings and ranking on the national concours exam for agregation?

Tags: ranking, academic-history

Are the *[École Normale Supérieure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_Normale_Sup%C3%A9rieure)*'s academic records publicly available anywhere?

Specifically, I would like to know what class rankings were historically there, as well as its students' rankings on the national *concours* exam for *[agrégation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agr%C3%A9gation)*.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found half the answer:

Here's the link to records for rankings in the *concours* exams for *aggrégation*:

**[Les agrégés de l'enseignement secondaire
Répertoire 1809-1950](http://www.inrp.fr/she/chervel_laureats.htm)**